# using apache stanbol for named entity recognition

Tags: apache, apache-stanbol

I am working on a project for NER and I have to use Apache Stanbol. Installing it from maven by compiling whole source is a big task and time consuming. Are there any prebuilt jars like  Apache Solr which has 'start.jar' in which it come as a webapp with Jetty server? Because then I can run the server straight away and start sending http request along with my content.

It is also hard to find the tutorial for Apache Stanbol installation and where I find, it is using maven and compiling the whole source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASF currently does not provide pre-built binaries. But according to [1], IKS (Interactive Knowledge Stack) [2] project offers what you want.

The main resources of reference are the official Stanbol website [3] and the mail list(dev@stanbol.apache.org). User issues are accepted in this dev mail group as Apache stanbol does not have a separate user mail list yet.

However, I recommend you to build from the source code.

[1] http://stanbol.apache.org/downloads/launchers.html

[2] http://www.iks-project.eu

[3] http://stanbol.apache.org

Hope this helps.

Comment: The IKS project ended in March 2013 and therefore, this project space is no longer maintained.